# Android Fused LocationSettingsRequest remove "never" option from startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

aAccording to this:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

You can check if location requirements are met and show a dialog if not, using `startResolutionForResult()`.

In that dialog, you can choose "ok", "not this time" or "never".

Is it possible to disable that "never" option?

Google Maps official app has that option disabled.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yup, so you would do it when you're building the settings request by using `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder.setAlwaysShow(true)`.  An example would look like this:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
                .setAlwaysShow(true);
```